# How to append items to an objects progamatically?

Tags: javascript

How can i append items to an object programmatically without having to hard-code the object key:

```
let myObject = {};
let list = ['seeds','leaves','branches'];
let list2 = ['100','1 million','22'];

// list2.forEach((item,index) => {
//  console.log(index);
// myObject.list[index] = item;
// });

for(i=0; i<list.length; i++){
  //console.log(list[i])
  myObject.list[i] = list2[i];
}
console.log(myObject);
```

**I want it to have an object like this**

```
{
seeds:'100',
leaves: '1 million',
branchces: '22'
}
```

when i run this however i get:

> error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Comment: Bracket notation: `myObject[list[i]] = list2[i]`

Comment: @IceMetalPunk brackets notion worked

Comment: https://riptutorial.com/javascript/example/8628/merge-two-array-as-key-value-pair

Comment: @Mikhaili thats a clever sneaky way